# mysql procedure error occurrence 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Tags: mysql, subquery, procedure

select query

```
    select concat('call db_name.tmp_proc(', '\'' , TABLE_SCHEMA, '\'' ',' , '\'' , TABLE_NAME  , '\'' ',30,1' ');' ) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='logdb';
    

    result  

    call db_name.tmp_proc('logdb','monthly_test',30,1); 
    call db_name.tmp_proc('logdb','monthly_test1',30,1);
    call db_name.tmp_proc('logdb','monthly_test2',30,1);
    call db_name.tmp_proc('logdb','monthly_test3',30,1);
    call db_name.tmp_proc('logdb','monthly_test4',30,1);

    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Create this query as a procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test() BEGIN 
DECLARE result INT default 0;  
SET @result = (select concat('call db_name.tmp_proc(', '\'' , TABLE_SCHEMA, '\'' ',' , '\'' , TABLE_NAME  , '\'' ',30,1' ');' ) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='logdb'); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @result;
EXECUTE stmt1;
END$$

call test$$

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

**ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row**

This error has occurred and cannot be executed.
Is there a way to eliminate errors and execute all queries of results?

============
============  
It was revised as follows with reference to the advice and performed well without errors.
Thank you.

```
delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test() BEGIN 
-- DECLARE result text(65535) ;  
-- DECLARE cnt int default 0;
DECLARE i int default 0;

SET @cnt = (select count(*) -1 as cnt FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='logdb' AND CREATE_OPTIONS ='partitioned' ) ;

WHILE i <= @cnt DO

SET @result = (select concat('call db_name.tmp_proc(', '\'' , TABLE_SCHEMA, '\'' ',' , '\'' , TABLE_NAME  , '\'' ',30,1' ')' ) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='logdb' limit i, 1) ;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @result;
EXECUTE stmt1;

SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END$$

call test$$
```

Comment: Not your error but dynamic sql can only execute 1 call statement at a time. Also the error may be coming from db_name.tmp_proc please publish that code.

Comment: Sorry, but there was no problem running db_name.tmp_proc alone. @P.Salmon

Comment: Then the select does indeed return more than 1 row and since you cannot submit more than 1 call at a time i suggest you push this into a cursor and loop through the cursor executing dynamic sql each time.

Comment: @user1819769 I think you need one more close parenthesis. `)` here `SET @result = (select concat('call db_name.tmp_proc(', '\'' , TABLE_SCHEMA, '\'' ',' , '\'' , TABLE_NAME  , '\'' ',30,1' ');' )`

Comment: To help others who may encounter a similar problem please publish your working code as an answer.